# Shrink-to-fit div and paragraph, based on image?

Tags: html, css

The code below is a simplified version of my website. On my site, the image width varies from page to page and the text is around 100 words. That means the paragraph stretches the DIV to be wider than the image. Using only CSS, is it possible to shrink the DIV and the paragraph to the width of the image?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WM6hK/)

[Example of what I'm trying to describe here](http://s15.postimage.org/7tt0qaym3/image.png). Top is what I'm getting, bottom is what I want.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
   display: inline-block;
   }
```

Comment: I lost you near `widest object on the`. Can you put a screenshot of what you're getting and what you need?

Comment: I haven't programmed it/thought it out well, but if every page has different image width, why not have a javascript(I am not much familiar with jQuery/AJAX) onload function, which sets your div width to the width of your image?

Comment: @hjpotter92 That is certainly an option. I was just wondering if it could be done without Javascript.

Comment: Found a similar reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920968/make-text-in-a-div-wrap-around-a-child-element

Comment: @hjpotter92, It is not similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And for doing anything table related I shall forever shame myself: http://jsfiddle.net/WM6hK/3/

```
div {
display: table;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 1%;
}

p {
border: 1px solid blue;
}​
```

Comment: Many thanks to you devs who think outside of the box.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this:-**

```
    div {
    width:20%;
    display:inline-table;
    }


p {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

It will totally work according to image size.....

**see the demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/WM6hK/11/

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible by only using CSS. You will need to set a width for the parent div and rescale your images.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding in a little jquery.. to make your life so much easier:

```
imgw = $("img").width();
$("div").css("width", imgw);
```

Here is how it would look: http://jsfiddle.net/WM6hK/2/

This way you can add this simple line of code to any div and just replace $("div") with and ID $("#idofdiv"). Hope this helps!

Comment: I may end up using this route, as it is cleaner. But the table option actually answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Right now its not possible, using CSS

Using jQuery, its as easy as this

```
$("div").width($("div img").width());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WM6hK/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS style to the parent div.

set the width of the parent div to width: fit-content.

this will make your parent div to shrink or expand based on the size of the child elements nested within it.

```css
    div {  
       width: fit-content;
       border: 3px solid red;
       text-align: center
     }
```

```html
 <div>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
 </div>
```