# Make Parent DIV Shrink-wrap Contents

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with an `img` and a `p` tag. I want the div to "shrink-wrap" the image and let the text organically wrap. However, I'm trying to do this with absolutely no javascript or constraints (ie width=300px / 50% etc) as my frame needs to be fluid.

Here's an example of something similar to what I have now: How can I make the outer dive match the size of the "Google" image without using fixed sizes or javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/pVF74/

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want the div to be the same width as the image, and the text to be under the image?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951300/shrink-to-fit-div-and-paragraph-based-on-image

Comment: @Adrift related content ftw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:table;
    width:1%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pVF74/2/

Comment: What is the reason for the 1%?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your div's class.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/r9rLr/

Comment: What does this change?

Comment: Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: You might be viewing this in a small window. Make sure your "Result" window is larger than the image.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 - no, it doesn't. At least not in Chrome.

Comment: i've seen this for quite a bit of answers.  Both it and the accepted answer don't help me out.  Just wanted to state that.  I'm still searching...